# Rails update database attribute without controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, associations, has-many-through

[Has Many - Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

My schema is same as in the Link above, i have to update the 'appointment_date' attribute in appointments table, but i have not created appointments_controller.
How can I update the value of appointment_date from Patient's Controller OR from Physician's Controller.
I have access to Patient_id and Physician_id in the current view.

Comment: Why haven't you created an appointments controller? How are you creating appointments? You can use any controller to do this i.e. find the object, update the attribute and save it but if you are doing a lot of work with appointments, it makes sense to do it in an appointments controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the appointment ID? If so then:

```
Appointment.find(appointment_id).update(apppointment_date: Time.now)
```